# $F$ is a field $\implies$ $1_F \neq 0_F$

Tags: ring-theory

I came across a step in a proof which stated :

$F$ is a field $\implies$ $1_F \neq 0_F$ .

but isn't it in general true even if it isn't a field...

Comment: Consider $R = \{0\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer if the ring contains both unity as well zero element .Isn't it true that they are different.... why only in fields..

Comment: If a ring has a unity, that unity is different from $0$ - unless the ring contains only one element.

Comment: @DanielFischer Then what about the step in question.Is it so because a field has to contain atleast 2 elements....

Comment: Yes. Although the fact that a field must contain at least two elements is a consequence of $1 \neq 0$ being part of the definition, in the usual exposition. One could also explicitly demand that a field contains at least two elements and from that deduce that $1\neq 0$ in a field, but that's not how it is usually done.

Comment: @DanielFischer Can we also have the axiom be "$0$ is not the multiplicative inverse of anything"?

Comment: @Ian That's another way to write $0 \neq 1$, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the definition of a field $F$, it is stated that it has a multiplicative identity $1 \in F \setminus \{0\}$, however in the definition of a general ring $R$, it is only stated that there exist $1 \in R$ such that $1 \dot a = a, \ \forall  \ a \in R$. You see that this property holds for $R = \{0\}$ with $1=0$, so in a general ring we might not have $1 \neq 0$. However as said above, in a field $F$ we have $1 \in F \setminus \{0\}$ by definition, so your implication holds.

See for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics), where it is said in the defintion that $1 \in F \setminus \{0\}$.

In writing this answer, I'm refering to the definitions stated in my textbook(s). You may have a different definition in your textbook ?